# iCarousel example projects not working?

Tags: ios, icarousel

I would be interested in implementing iCarousel in my App. To begin with I've tried to check out the example projects.

But I get errors and therefor wonder if someone experienced the same thing? And knows how to correct them?

Regards

[image]

Comment: What version of Xcode are you using?

Comment: And can you show the code before the first line inour screen shot. This sort of problem is often caused by a missing;

Comment: Which specific example project are you using while experiencing this errors? I just downloaded the repository and everything works fine for me! Try redownloading it https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel

Comment: I am using Xcode 6.1.1. Well I have no "code" since I am only trying to start the example projects. Same problem in all of them. For the moment I am trying Basic iOS Example project... I have tried to redownload from git but same problem over and over again :(

Answer (score 0):

I updated Xcode and it solved the problem.